# How to use ign service in command line?

Tags: gazebo-citadel, gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm not quite familiar with this. Do you know how to use ignition.msgs in command line? I was following this [doc](https://gazebosim.org/api/msgs/6.1/classignition_1_1msgs_1_1Entity.html#a8d055df87f4bc1130fb42503f01b4c92)

using EntityFactory which is `ignition.msgs.EntityFactory` in command line. I wanted to clear sensors to 0 so I used `SENSOR` or `Clear()`

So I tried many ways include

```
ign service -s /world/free_world/create --reqtype ignition.msgs.EntityFactory --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean  --timeout 300 --req 'clear'

ign service -s /world/free_world/create --reqtype ignition.msgs.EntityFactory --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean  --timeout 300 --req 'clear: true'

ign service -s /world/free_world/create --reqtype ignition.msgs.EntityFactory --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean  --timeout 300 --req 'clear = true'
```

None of them worked. Error just returns like this,
`[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:307] Error parsing text-format ignition.msgs.EntityFactory: 1:7: Message type "ignition.msgs.EntityFactory" has no field named "clear".`

I wanted to do this because of respawn. This sensor is actually prevent the respawn due to error where it says camera rgb is already exist in entity [#]. I explained more in [github](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/issues/1489) but then I realized, this is just belong to this site

Last question, do you know if there's any documentation or tutorial for this one?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28128/how-to-use-ign-service-in-command-line?/) by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 87 on 2022-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I finally find out about this.

So, basically...you just run this command after `ign service -l` and then select one you wanted to use. For me, I used `create`, so it would be `ignition.msgs.EntityFactory,`

How do I know that it would be ignition.msgs.EntityFactory? Well, you type in terminal, `ign service -is /world/free_world/create`

and you get the output:

```
Service providers [Address, Request Message Type, Response Message Type]:
  tcp://172.17.0.1:40725, ignition.msgs.EntityFactory, ignition.msgs.Boolean
```

So, it says `ignition.msgs.EntityFactory`, go to [msg api](https://gazebosim.org/libs/msgs) (Use this since it gives you the latest version) and then click api and tutorials. Replace `index.html` to `EntityFactory.html` which is like [this](https://gazebosim.org/api/msgs/8.4/classignition_1_1msgs_1_1EntityFactory.html)

So, you can see where extra arguments come from.

So as for `/world` commands, I guess each end of the line is the command. In this case, I picked `create` out of `/world/free_world/create`.

More information is at this: https://gazebosim.org/api/gazebo/6.9/entity_creation.html

Now we know how to work with ign service usage.

---

Originally posted by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) with karma: 87 on 2022-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0